# OCaml type constructor help. I need to understand this further

Tags: ocaml

An ordered list is a list in which an element that appears later in the list is never smaller than an element that appears earlier in the list, where the notion of "smaller than" is given by a specific chosen relation. For example, the list

```
   [1; 5; 7; 12; 13]
```

is an ordered list relative to the usual < relation on numbers, the list

```
   [17; 14; 9; 6; 2]
```

is an ordered list relative to the > relation on numbers but not relative to the < order and the list

```
  [17; 14; 9; 13; 2]
```

How would I define a type constructor olist that is like the list type constructor except that values of this type carry enough information to determine whether or not they are ordered lists relative to the intended ordering relation?

For example, I need a funciton of

```
initOList : ('a -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a olist
```

that takes an ordering relation over a given type and returns an empty olist of that type. Where do I beging with creating this type instructor and use it for creating the initOList function?

Comment: This sounds like an assignment, which are typically intended to be solved by you, not by us. The description is also a bit vague, in that it's not clear what "like the list type constructor" means. You should show us what you've tried, and what specifically you're struggling with, otherwise this question is too broad and likely considered off-topic.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. An ordinary list carries enough information to determine if it's ordered. You could bundle a list with an ordering relation, and thus be able to tell if it's ordered according to the relation. More fancy types (that can represent only ordered values, say) aren't really practical in OCaml (IMHO). But you can use the module system (with abstract types) to enforce any desired invariants.

Comment: This is not an off-topic discussion as it relates to  OCaml. I need to create a type constructor of olist that is bound to the rules of ordered lists, but I am having a hard time grasping the concept behind it.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: I think it is a good and interesting question. It is indeed not totally clear, what OP is asking, but, common, this is why he or she is asking. It's hard to form a clear question involving a concept that you do not fully grasp. Given that OCaml tag traffic is rather low, we can try to answer all questions, even those that do not really excellent to the SO standards.

Comment: The question is interesting, but given it's a school assignment, giving a complete answer is not a good idea. And without examples and code snippets, the answer loses a lot of its interest for further readers.

Comment: I'm not really sure, that it is an assignment. Looks like an advanced question after a lecture. And yes, I'm always trying to give a fishing rod, rather than the fish itself. So I hope, that OP will at least read my answer, and will get some insights.

Comment: this is what I have so far type 'a olist = 
   Empty
|  List of 'a * 'a olist * 'a olist. I am unsure how to define a function initOlist as described above.

Answer (score 2):

A static type represents some property of an expression that can be checked at the compile time, i.e., without relying on any information that is available only at runtime. So you can't really express in the type systems things that depend on runtime values, such as the list length, ordering, contents, etc.

In your particular case, you want to have a type constructor that takes an ordering and returns a new type. However, type constructors are functions in the type domain, i.e., they map types to types (i.e., take types as their parameters and return types). But ordering is a function of type `'a -> 'a -> int`, so you can't really express it in OCaml.

A type system that allows values to appear in the domain of type constructors (i.e., to parametrize types with the runtime values) is called Dependent Type systems. OCaml doesn't really provide dependent typing. This is not because it is impossible to do this, this is a matter of choice, as working with the dependent typing system is much harder, moreover, type inference in the dependent type systems it is undecidable (i.e., it is impossible to write an algorithm that will work for all programs), so a significant help from a user is usually required to prove that a program is well-typed. Thus the systems that implement the Dependent Typing are more close to automated theorem provers, e.g., [Coq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq), [Isabelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabelle_(proof_assistant)), etc. However, there are those that are more close to conventional programming languages, e.g., [F*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F*_(programming_language)).

So now, we are clear, that in OCaml a type cannot be parametrized with a runtime value. However, the typing system still provides enough power to express a notion of a sorted list. We can't really use the type system to check that our sorting algorithm is correct, but we can tell it, that hey, this function *ensures* that a list is sorted, just believe us, and take it as granted. We can represent this using the module level abstraction, e.g.,

```
module SortedList : sig 
  type 'a t
  val create : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a t
end = struct
  type 'a t = 'a list
  let create = List.sort
end
```

The idea is that we have type `'a SortedList.t` that can be only constructed with the `SortedList.create` function and there are no other ways around it. So an expression that has type `'a SortedList.t` bears a proof in itself, that it is sorted. We can use it to make preconditions of functions explicit in the type system, e.g., suppose we have a `dedup` function that removes duplicates from a list, and it works correctly if the input list is sorted. We can't really test this precondition, thus we may rely on a type system:

```
val dedup : 'a SortedList.t -> 'a SortedList.t
```

Thus the dedup function type states that (a) it is applicable only to sorted lists, and (b) it preserves the ordering.

There are two issues with our approach. First of all, our `'a SortedList.t` is too abstract, as it doesn't provide any access operators. We can just provide a `to_list` operator, that will erase the proof that a list is ordered, but allow all the list operations on it, e.g.,

```
module SortedList : sig 
  type 'a t
  val create : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a t
  val to_list : 'a t -> 'a list
end = struct
  type 'a t = 'a list
  let create = List.sort
  let to_list xs = xs
end
```

The `to_list` operation is correct, as a set of all sorted lists is a subset of all lists. That means, that `'a SortedList.t` is actually a subtype of `'a list`. It is nice, that OCaml provides an explicit mechanism for expressing this subtype relation via private abstract types.

```
module SortedList : sig 
  type 'a t = private 'a list
  val create : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a list -> 'a t
end = struct
  type 'a t = 'a list
  let create = List.sort
end
```

Such definition of a type states that `'a SortedList.t` is a subtype of `'a list` so it is possible to upcast one into another. Remember, since upcasting is explicit in OCaml, it is not automatic, so you need to use the upcasting operator, e.g., `xs : 'a SortedList.t :> 'a list`.

The second problem in our implementation is that our `'a SortedList.t` doesn't really distinguish list that are differently sorted, i.e., ascending or descending. It's not a problem for the `dedup` function, but some functions may require that their input is sorted in a specific order (for example a function that will find a median or any other statistic mode). So we need to encode the ordering. We will encode ordering in such way, that we will treat each ordering function as a different type. (An alternative solution would be just to encode concrete variants, such as `Ascending` and `Descending`, but I will leave this is an exercise). The main drawback of our approach is that our ordered list can't be a parametric type anymore, as the ordering function is defined for a particular ground type. In fact, this means, that our OrderedList.t is now a higher order polymorphic type, so we need to use functors to implement it:

```
module type Ordering = sig
  type element
  type witness

  val compare : element -> element -> int
end

module SortedList  : sig

  type ('a,'o) t = private 'a list

  module Make(Order : Ordering) : sig
    type nonrec t = (Order.element, Order.witness) t
    val create : Order.element list -> t
  end

end = struct

  type ('a,'o) t = 'a list

  module Make(Order : Ordering) = struct
    type nonrec t = (Order.element, Order.witness) t
    let create = List.sort Order.compare
  end
end
```

Now, let's play a little bit with our implementation. Let's provide to different Orders:

```
module AscendingInt = struct
  type element = int
  type witness = Ascending_int
  let compare : int -> int -> int = compare
end

module DescendingInt = struct
  type element = int
  type witness = Descending_int
  let compare : int -> int -> int = fun x y -> compare y x
end


module AscendingSortedList = SortedList.Make(AscendingInt)
module DescendingSortedList = SortedList.Make(DescendingInt)
```

Now, let's test that the two sorted lists are actually having different types:

```
# let asorted = AscendingSortedList.create [3;2;1];;
val asorted : AscendingSortedList.t = [1; 2; 3]
# let bsorted = DescendingSortedList.create [3;2;1];;
val bsorted : DescendingSortedList.t = [3; 2; 1]
# compare asorted bsorted;;
Characters 16-23:
  compare asorted bsorted;;
                  ^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type
         DescendingSortedList.t =
           (DescendingInt.element, DescendingInt.witness) SortedList.t
       but an expression was expected of type
         AscendingSortedList.t =
           (AscendingInt.element, AscendingInt.witness) SortedList.t
       Type DescendingInt.witness is not compatible with type
         AscendingInt.witness
```

Now let's check that both of them are actually subtypes of `'a list`:

```
# compare (asorted :> int list) (bsorted :> int list);;
- : int = -1
```

Comment: The timing between your answer and my comment on the question was on point.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition you've provided, an `olist` is simply a `list` with a comparison function attached to it. This can be easily achieved using *records* (you can read more about them [here](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/records.html)).

From there, you can write functions that creates and manipulates values of your new type.

## We need to go deeper

If you've managed to implement the solution above, I suggest you put all your definitions inside a *module*. You can read more about these [here](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/files-modules-and-programs.html). Put simply, modules are a way to put your type definition and your functions together.